# How to merge / combine / extend type declarations

Tags: typescript

In typescript, how can I create a new type from multiple type declarations in an outer join kind of way ?

I have 2 type declarations

```
type OverflowPosition = "safe" | "unsafe" | "";
type BaselinePosition = "baseline" | "center";
```

I would like to see them combined to

```
type OverflowBaselinePosition = "safe baseline" | "safe center" | "unsafe baseline" | "unsafe center" | "baseline" | "center" ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html), e.g.

```
type OverflowPosition = "safe" | "unsafe" | "";
type BaselinePosition = "baseline" | "center";

type CombinedPosition = `${OverflowPosition} ${BaselinePosition}`
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gbhATgMwDYHsDuAFdBnAS2APQDsoBeKAIjwENkJqoAfGgV1PsebeuoDcAWABQoSFABCdPBFQFSEXIWJlKNAEYy5CpqxoBjCKWBJBo0eOgBhdAFsNugCbKiJclQAGAEgDe8JDQsV1VSAF8oP2lZeUUQ9zDPCxEDMjxgKAgADzo7MFQIAC4oWwdneLUqWgZoLRjdQSA)